# Copy to Publish Directory output of PreBuild Event

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, csproj

Inside my csproj I have a pre-build event where I run the build of Vue js project. It outputs to a "dist" folder, and that is loaded by an cshtml file.

In the csproj file I have a reference to the dist folder and I tell it to copy to publish directory:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="dist\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
</ItemGroup>
```

On publish, MsBuild seems to be trying to copy the files in the dist folder that exist before the pre-build event starts. Is there an way to get MsBuild to copy the contents of the folder after the pre-build event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to support all possible publish mechanisms that tooling (VS etc.) supports, I suggest setting it up similar to how the in-box angular template works:

```
<Target Name="PublishDistFiles" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
  <ItemGroup>
    <DistFiles Include="dist\**" />
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
      <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: With "single file publish" available, I would add `<ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>` after the `CopyToPublishDirectory` element.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a step to do it manually using the [Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2017)

```
<Target Name="MyCopyStep" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
  <ItemGroup>
     <MyDistFiles Include="dist\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyDistFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(MyDistFiles->'$(PublishDir)\dist\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: Note that the copy taks relies on the system using file system publish. There may be other publishing or packing operations not executing the copy stage of publishing (such as tool package creation) which is why I recommend hooking after `ComputeFilesToPublish` as described in my answer.

Comment: @MartinUllrich Thanks for the clarification. I actually don't know that much about csproj build steps and posted what's likely a hack implemented a former employee. Is there a place where the targets (like ComputeFilesToPublish) and tasks (like CopyToPublishDirectory) are documented or is the only way to copy Microsoft's templates?

Comment: Documentation on build steps is spread out over multiple docs, but I don't know of good ones about .net core specific steps (publish for instance). I usually use the build source code for the .NET Sdk or MSBuild itself on GitHub to determine how to extend my build definitions.